# How to have curly brace inside f string

Tags: python

I am trying the below in python with f string

```
test=f"""
{
"""

print(test)
```

It gives the error

```
  Input In [39]
    """
       ^
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

I want it to print `{` as it is

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
test = f"""{{"""
print(test)
```

or

```
test = f"{'{'}"
print(test)
```